# How to tap on a node using accessibility that is not clickable by service but clickable by user?

Tags: android, accessibility

Recently discovered an app that contains a toolbar of items. All items are clickable by the user via screen. 
One item is completely ignored by the AccessibilityService. It does not accept focus, TalkBack/Vysor and other apps are completely ignoring it. But user can press it.

Item contain few children and they don't respond to clicks.
The parent is the toolbar itself and it also doesn't receive clicks.

Any ideas how this is achieved and how to click on it using a service?

Comment: It sounds like the item that is ignored by accessibility services has the `android:importantForAccessibility" attribute set to either "no" or "noHideDescendants". Do you have access to the code?

Comment: no. I don't have the code. Its 3rd party app

Comment: Did you find the solution?